# Codeigniter image name send to data base as name

Tags: php, codeigniter

is this thing do is possible?
I want to send data and image name  to database please help me to fix this error
i this image text name not send to db thats why there was a error please help me to fix this error
this is my controller

```
public function upload_file()
    {
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
        $config['file_name'] = $data-> 'filename';
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/Ehi';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = false;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) 
        {
            print_r($this->upload->data());

            $this->load->model('ehi_model');
            $data  = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'), 
            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'activedays' => $this->input->post('activedays'),
            'filename' => $data-> 'filename';


        );
        $this->ehi_model->upload_file($data);

        redirect(base_url() ."Ehi/index");

        }
        else
        {
            print_r($this->upload->display_error());
        }

    }
```

[image]

and this is my model

```
function upload_file($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('ehi', $data);
    }
```

Comment: are you retrive full data with `text & image` in `$data` array correctly??

Answer (score 1):

Where is this `$data` defined?

```
$config['file_name'] = $data-> 'filename';
```

But following change will work for you.

```
'filename' => $this->upload->data('file_name')
```

[Reference](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::data)

Comment: when i change my code it works idk what happened anyway thanks for the reply bro

Answer (score 0):

Use that.

```
$this->ehi_model->upload_file($this->upload->data('file_name'));
```